# What date format does Facebook use for the expiration access_token?

Tags: .net, facebook

I'm trying to make sure I get the conversion to DateTime right, using a .Net service to connect want want to store the expiration in a database for later use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about the expires parameter that comes back with the access_token, then it is seconds until it expires.

Do

```
DateTime expires = DateTime.UtcNow;
expires.AddSeconds(seconds);
```

and there is your expiry date.

Comment: Whoa. The rest of the internet told me it's unix time. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it is epoch. I changed the answer above to reflect that. It's 1am, I really need to go to bed :)

Comment: Is it any different for sandboxed applications? I'm getting very strange looking date-times.

Comment: whats the number you are getting?

Comment: This is not correct. The expires that comes back is in seconds, and you have to add it to the CURRENT DateTime. (For this endpoint: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{appId}&client_secret=#{secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=#{token} )

Answer (score 5):

Looks like things were changed yet again. Multiply the returned expiration value (expires_at) by 1000 to get the epoch. In JavaScript anyways, the expiration can be calculated with:

```
new Date(expires_at * 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the below endpoint, the expires value that comes back is in seconds from NOW. So, add those seconds to the CURRENT time and you'll have your expiration date.

endpoint: 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{appId}&client_secret=#{secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=#{token}

Answer (score 1):

The expire value that Facebook provides is a UTC difference. If you add it to current UTC, then you have the expiration value. Tricky huh? Why they don't just give you the UTC of the expiration is beyond me.

If you want to get the real value in javascript you need to know that the expire value is missing the milliseconds. So, in order to get the real expiration date you need to multiply by 1000 to get the milliseconds back then add it to the UTC date value of when the token was requested, then new up a Date with that value.

http://jsfiddle.net/donrolling/ng331yta/1/

```
var exampleExpiration = 5181776 * 1000;//have to add milliseconds in
var now = new Date().getTime();
alert(new Date(now + exampleExpiration));
```

Comment: is the difference from my client time, from the server time, from the time the request was sent, from the time it was received... from when?

Comment: Yeah, good question. I just use the current time that I get the response. That should be close enough and within milliseconds. They specifically say that the expiration date may not be correct and can expire at any time.
Welcome to working with Facebook.